# How to make single linked list generic in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a implementation of a single linked list which workw fine with `int`. I would like to make it generics without inheritance. My data for testing are electrical signals and I need to measure execution time of filling it. I don't need to add any new method, everything is fine, just need to make it as a template/generics. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Here is my code...

```
public class LinkedList
    {
        //structure
        private Node head;
        private int count;

        public LinkedList()
        {
            //constructor
        }

        public bool IsEmpty
        {
            //check if list is empty or not
        }

        public int Count
        {
            //count items in the list
        }

        public object Add(int index, object o)
        {
            //add items to the list from beginning/end  
        }

        public object Delete(int index)
        {
            //delete items of the list from beginning/end   
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            //clear the list    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post a little Code of your list Implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your LinkedList should look like this

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    public class Node<T>
    {
        public T data;
        public Node<T> next;
    }

    //structure
    private Node<T> head;
    private int count;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        //constructor
    }

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        //check if list is empty or not
    }

    public int Count
    {
        //count items in the list
    }

    public T Add(int index, T o)
    {
        //add items to the list from beginning/end  
    }

    public T Delete(int index)
    {
        //delete items to the list from beginning/end   
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        //clear the list    
    }
}
```

I've implemented one here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138142/linked-list-in-c

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback. @fubo

Answer (score 1):

1. Change all instances of the linked list's element type from `int` to `T`. (Don't blindly change *all* `int` - just the ones that you're using to hold the elements. So don't change `count` or `index`, for example!)
2. Change the class declaration to `public class LinkedList<T>`
3. Attempt to compile it and fix any errors.
4. Update your unit tests so that they compile, and ensure that they still all pass. (You *do* have unit tests for your linked-list, right? ;)

I'm not sure about your `object` parameters. Perhaps they should be changed to `T` too.

You don't show the `Node` implementation, but I'm guessing that you'll have to do something similar for that: Make it `Node<T>` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the class as `LinkedList<T>`, where `T` is the generic type, then modify your `Add` method to accept an object of type `T`: `public object Add(int index, T element)`